# Unable to generate ANTLR 4 listener through Visual Studio 2012

Tags: visual-studio-2012, antlr4

I'm trying to follow the guidelines as outlined in https://github.com/tunnelvisionlabs/antlr4cs.

I'm using ANTLR Language Support extension.

The problem is that I don't get the generated files.
The properties seem OK - I see custom tool MSBuild:Compile but nothing happens when I try to rebuild the project.

What am I missing?

Thanks,
Ron

Answer (score -1, accepted):

OK, after searching for an answer I've finally found one [here](https://docs.google.com/viewer?a=v&pid=forums&srcid=MDAyODQ5NzEwMDExOTYzMDA2MTYBMDE5NDc5NTMwNDIxMjY0NjQ0ODABNWhxTF8wUTBaeWNKATQBAXYy) 
Seems I needed to add another nuget package at the project level and that's responsible for actually generating the source files from the g4 file.

Comment: Can you include the relevant text from the link here? The link appears to no longer work so this answer isn't helpful to others.

Comment: @SamHarwell and anybody who reaches this point, Ron may be referring to Antlr4.CodeGenerator in nuget, authored by Sam Harwell and Terrance Parr. That worked for me, at least.

Answer (score 2):

The files are generated in the **obj/Debug** or **obj/Release** folder, depending on your active build configuration. They will not appear in the Solution Explorer, but the MSBuild configuration instructs Visual Studio to generate and locate the files for IntelliSense purposes from the moment they are saved.

*Note:* some build platform configurations and/or modifications to the project file can result in the generated files being placed in a different intermediate output folder. The folders mentioned above are simply the most frequently used folders.